# Question regarding sagemaker pipeline example on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

In the sagemaker pipeline example shown here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/define-pipeline.html

I see two lines joining from AbaloneProcess to AbaloneTrain and AbaloneEval respectively. However, based on the code, I would expect it to actually be connected from AbaloneTrain only, then to AbaloneEval in a single path. Can somebody explain to me what is actually happening here because I am struggling to wrap my head around this. Much appreciated and apologies for the inconvenience in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connections are indicated data dependencies between steps, not only the order of execution. This is what you see AbaloneProcess connected to AbaloneEval, since the output of AbaloneProcess is used in AbaloneEval.